# change css3 animation of drop-shadow by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I gave my img style using css3 -webkit-animation.  this css chages a drop-shadow style animated from one property to another. (blink)

THIS IS THE CSS

```
.firstglow {
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: hide 0.3s linear 0s infinite alternate;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
    0% {-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 40px rgba(255,251,0,1)); }
    100% { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px rgba(255,251,0,0.5)); }
}
```

I need to change my code dynamicly by javascript and changing the color element

This is the jQuery I tried:

```
$('.firstglow').css("-webkit-animation","newGlow 0.5s linear 0s infinite alternate;");

var lastSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
lastSheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes newGlow { 0% {-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px      3px 40px " +  myCharacterColor + " 1)); } 100% { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px" + myCharacterColor + "0.5)); } }", lastSheet.cssRules.length);
```

this is the fidle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VbzFj/

Comment: What is your question? Could illustrate it with some code?

Comment: That's great that you have to do that. But if you want us to help you, at least try to make clear to us what you want. Give an example, give us the code you already have. *What have you tried*.

Comment: .firstglow
{  
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: hide 0.3s linear 0s infinite alternate;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide{
    0% {-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 40px rgba(255,251,0,1)); }
    100% { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px rgba(255,251,0,0.5)); }

Comment: Put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VbzFj/

Comment: @user1463227 :where is your variable `myCharacterColor` declared and initialized

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('.firstglow').css("-webkit-animation", "newGlow 0.5s linear 0s infinite alternate");

    var lastSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
    myCharacterColor = 'rgba(182, 17, 17, 0.5)';

    var styelRule = "";

    if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
        styelRule = '@-webkit-keyframes newGlow{0%{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(3px 3px 40px ' + myCharacterColor + ');}100%{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px ' + myCharacterColor + ');}}';
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
        styelRule = '@-moz-keyframes newGlow{0%{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(3px 3px 40px ' + myCharacterColor + ');}100%{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px ' + myCharacterColor + ');}}';
    }
    else {
        styelRule = '@keyframes newGlow{0%{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(3px 3px 40px ' + myCharacterColor + ');}100%{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px ' + myCharacterColor + ');}}';
    }

    lastSheet.insertRule(styelRule, lastSheet.cssRules.length);
});
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VbzFj/2/)**.